# Python gets 'permission denied' to a file in Linux

Tags: python, django, linux, apache

I have a method to log actions on a json file:

```
def log(self, action, data):
    import json
    import os

    current_directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

    try:
        with open(current_directory+'/logs/log_'+str(data['id'])+'.json', 'a+') as outfile:
            log_data = {
                str(datetime.today()): {
                    'action': action,
                    'data': data
                }
            }
            json.dump(log_data, outfile, indent=2)
    except Exception as e:
        print('\033[91m'+"Couldn't access log file to log changes in Reservation model: [{}]".format(str(e))+'\033[0m')
        print('Current directory is {}'.format(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
```

It works locally on my mac, but it always returns `permission denied` in Linux server. The **logs** directory permissions is set to `755` with `chmod`, but I still get the same error:

```
[Wed Nov 28 16:27:23.551207 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18955:tid 139905951835904] [remote 189.149.229.31:63243] \x1b[91mCouldn't access log file to log changes in Reservation model: [[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/axel/IntellibookProject/Intellibook/ReservationsManagerApp/logs/log_43.json']\x1b[0m
[Wed Nov 28 16:27:23.551346 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 18955:tid 139905951835904] [remote 189.149.229.31:63243] Current directory is /home/axel/IntellibookProject/Intellibook/ReservationsManagerApp
```

Comment: does the `logs` directory exist? if not create it.

Comment: Yest, it does. When it doesn't, I get a different error code

Comment: what about the permissions on the logs directory? can you create a file by hand inside it?

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre Yes, I can,

Comment: why "a+" mode? try just "a". And check if the file doesn't already exist before writing to it. Maybe the _file_ cannot be overwritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever is the user running the python script seems to be lacking the permissions to access the directory - see if using chown to set the owner of the directory solves your problem.

For example: 'sudo chown -R someuser /path/to/the/directory'

"-R"option means the owner is set to the directory and all content in it

On CentOS and RHEL like systems you might need to set SE Linux context to allow writing to the specific directory. To temporarily disable SE Linux to check if it's a SE Linux problem, type 'sudo setenforce 0' (applicable only with systems with SE Linux, like RHEL, CentOS, Fedora, Oracle Linux, SUSE, OpenSUSE, and others).